# How to Exclude 0 values from my =Count formula?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

DESPERATE for any help :-)
I need to exclude 0 values from my =COUNT excel formula in order to get an automated frequency value feeding another formula in my model.

Actual Base Formula:
=COUNT(J10,J11,J12,N10,N11,N12,J14,J15,J16,N14,N15,N16)

I am trying to get the formula to NOT count when any of these cells have O values. For instance, if J10 is greater than 0, include it in the count.

I have tried several different "IF" statements, but am failing miserably!

I basically need to dummy proof this by automating it versus having users simply count the cells with values and enter the number into the frequency field for my score calculator. Thanks so much for any help!!

Answer (score 1):

Since your range is disjointed the best method is four(4) countifs:

```
=COUNTIF(J10:J12,">0")+COUNTIF(N10:N12,">0")+COUNTIF(J14:J16,">0")+COUNTIF(N14:N16,">0")
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed based on the comments.

=COUNTIF(J10:J12,">0")+COUNTIF(N10:N12,">0")+COUNTIF(J14:J16,">0")+COUNTIF(N14:N16,">0")

Comment: No countif will not work with a disjointed range regardless if it is a named range or not.

Comment: Ah fair point.


=COUNTIF(J10:J12,">0")+COUNTIF(N10:N12,">0")+COUNTIF(J14:J16,">0")+COUNTIF(N14:N16,">0")

Comment: This totally worked! I just finished testing the model. You gents are the best! Thank you very much for your help!